# Spring Cloud (2021.0.3) - Kafka Streams with Schema Registry Setup

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, debezium, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

What is the proper way to setup spring cloud streams using the kafka-streams binder to work with a Kafka schema registry? I am currently using Debezium for CDC, and I setup the [Apicurio](https://www.apicur.io/registry/docs/apicurio-registry/2.4.x/index.html) schema registry as specified in the Debezium docs. I was able to have avro messages being sent to the Kafka topic, and the schema for these messages are being added to the Apicurio registry (see screenshot).

[image]

I tried setting the properties specified in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_how_do_i_use_native_serializer_and_deserializer_instead_of_message_conversion_done_by_spring_cloud_stream) section of the spring cloud kafka docs, but the consumer was still trying to read the message as JSON no matter what I did.

```
  @Bean
  public Consumer<KStream<Key, Value>> capacityExport() {
    return message -> message.filter((k, v) -> v != null)
        .foreach((k, v) -> processEvent(v));
  }
```

Above is my consumer code, which uses the Key and Value classes which are plain Java POJOs in my application.

Doing some more reading, I was able to switch the key serializer / deserializer for the specific binding using this configuration, as the kakfa-streams binder appeared to use these configuration properties when initializing the deserializers.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          bindings:
            capacityExport-in-0:
              consumer:
                configuration:
                  key.deserializer: io.apicurio.registry.serde.avro.AvroKafkaDeserializer
                  value.deserializer: io.apicurio.registry.serde.avro.AvroKafkaDeserializer
                  apicurio.registry.url: http://172.64.5.254:8080
                  schema.registry.url: http://172.64.5.254:8080
                  specific.avro.reader: true
                key-serde:  io.apicurio.registry.serde.avro.AvroSerde
                value-serde: io.apicurio.registry.serde.avro.AvroSerde
```

I then received the following error message

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException invoking processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record, and value: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record.
Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:150) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:731) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:809) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:731) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1296) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:784) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.1.jar:na]
```

From this message, I gather that it's failing to deserialize the `Key` and `Value` classes because it's expecting a (autogenerated?) avro class, and naturally there isn't one. I'm aware that one typical case is to probably use the Maven Avro generator plugin to generate Java source classes, but I feel like doing that would defeat the whole purpose of using Schema registration in the register.

Is there a way to have the avro schemas defined in the registry, and have Spring Cloud Stream use these registries, and then deserialize into normal Java Pojos? I feel like I'm missing something or conflating two different concepts, because this is getting harder then it should be. I see examples using the Spring project schema registry [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/schema-registry-samples/schema-registry-vanilla-kafka-binder/kafka-streams-consumer), and I'm thinking maybe I should just switch to that registry because it has better integration?

Any help would be much appreciated; I just wanted to use the CDC aspect of Debezium, and I am a Kafka novice.

Comment: Can you set up a small Spring Boot application with your configuration and a brief README to run it? Then we should be able to look at this further.

Comment: Please show your Key and Value classes. As the error says, those are not Avro GenericRecord subclasses. Read the Avro documentation for how to generate Java classes from a Schema. You do not write those classes yourself

Comment: @OneCricketeer If the schema is stored in the schema registry and not locally in my project, how should I go about with the Maven Avro plugin doing this? Should I
1. Add the schema to the registry 
2. Point the maven plugin to the registry and generated the avro 
3. Use the avro classes in my code?

Comment: @LawrenceBeutlich 1. Make sure that the AvroSerde is configured to use the Apicurio schema registry. You can do that by setting the `apicurio.registry.url` property in the configuration map for both the key and value deserializers.

Comment: 2. Make sure that the Key and Value classes in your consumer code are compatible with the Avro schema that is registered in the Apicurio schema registry. If you prefer not to use code generation, you can manually create the Java classes to match the Avro schema in the registry. You can then annotate the classes with the @AvroSchema annotation from the io.confluent.kafka.serializers package to indicate the schema that should be used for serialization and deserialization.

Comment: @LawrenceBeutlich The Avro Maven plugin requires local files. It cannot read from a registry... Confluent has their own Maven plugin for reading from their Registry, but I don't know if Apicurio has the same. The alternative is to download the `.avsc` file locally, manually, or using other maven plugins like `maven-download-plugin`